# How to resolve shared library linking during compilation( GCC )?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have built **libshared.so** with is dependent on **libshared_dependent.so**

Now, I am compiling **app.bin** which is using **libshared.so**, Now at compile time gcc wants me to specify **-lshared_dependent** other wise it gives error that some symbols not found.

Is there any way by which, At compile time I don't need to specify **-lshared_dependent**, I want that just specifying **-lshared** works?

Comment: @Sateesh It requires me to change lots and lots of makefiles. I have changed one shared file's dependancy and now I don't want to change other project's makefiles.

Comment: But why you don't want to specify the dependency library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to link libshared.so to  libshared_dependent.so when you are producing  libshared.so.

```
gcc -shared -o libshared.so -lshared_dependant file1.o file2.o
```

This way, when you link your app to libshared.so it'll also link to whatever libshared.so depends on

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to have app.bin link with libshared_dependent.so.

That said, the linker will want to verify the symbols in libshared.so can be found so it will need to  locate libshared_dependent.so in order to do that.  If libshared_dependent.so is in a different directory then libshared.so, you will want to specify the path to libshared_dependent.so using the linker option -rpath-link.

Because -rpath-link is a linker option, you will need to tell gcc to pass it through to the linker:

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link,/directory-that-libshared_dependent-is-in
```